# Was steckt hinter der Abkürzung "b. b."?

Tags: abbreviation, legal-terminology

In einer Gerichtsklage sind Beweise, und zwar Zeugnisse der Personen mit deren Adressen vereinzelt aufgeführt. Wo eine Person wiederholt genannt ist, steht "b. b." anstelle von der Adresse. Welcher Ausdruck wird denn so abgekürzt?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In juristischen Schriftstücken steht die Abkürzung "b. b." für

> bereits benannt

Dabei wird die Abkürzung üblicherweise hinter den Namen gesetzt, wenn die Adresse bereits genannt wurde.